# Insert a line after current line if line before it matches some pattern using sed ;

Tags: linux, sed

I'm looking for a sed command to add instruction after a line matching pattern if line before it contains some string too. Hard to tell so here's the input :

```
if [ $coderet -ne 0 ];then
#  $UXEXE/uxset msg "*** KO *** voir log systeme ***"
exit 1
fi

if [ $coderet -ne 0 ];
  then
#  $UXEXE/uxset msg "*** KO *** voir log systeme ***"
exit 1
fi
```

I want to add `echo ""` after line that matches `#  $UXEXE/uxset msg` if line before it contains string `then` so expected result would look like :

```
if [ $coderet -ne 0 ];then
#  $UXEXE/uxset msg "*** KO *** voir log systeme ***"
  echo ""
  exit 1
fi

if [ $coderet -ne 0 ];
  then
#  $UXEXE/uxset msg "*** KO *** voir log systeme ***"
  echo ""
  exit 1
fi
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

I tried several things without much result! Sorry!

Comment: Does the `a` command of sed do what you want?  If not, what do you need that it doesn't provide?

Comment: The code in your question looks more like shell script than sed.

Comment: Please edit your question to include (what you think is) your best attempt with sed to achieve your requirement. We can't help you fix "it" if we can't see "it". (We're not going to write it for you) . Good luck.

Comment: See the [Sed Tutorial](https://grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) and read about the `n N H` commands (probably others).

Comment: It would be dead pointless to post what i've been trying to code for hours without much success. Funny how you don't understand how stuck people can be.
Thanks anyway

Comment: @TobySpeight The shell script is the input for sed to modify.

Comment: why does indentation of `exit 1` lines change?

Comment: So where is the sed program, then?

Comment: Posting sample input that ALWAYS matches the desired criteria means we can't adequately test a potential solution as all we can test is the success case, none of the failure cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution in awk is straightforward:

```
awk '{
    print
    if (prev_had_then && index($0, "#  $UXEXE/uxset msg"))
        print "  echo \"\""
    prev_had_then = /then/
}' file
```

sed is not much more complex:

```
sed '
    /then/ {
        N
        /#  \$UXEXE\/uxset msg/ a\
  echo ""
    }
' file
```